# "X's Y stage" vs "X's stage of Y."

Tags: sentence-construction

"X's Y stage" vs "X's stage of Y." Is the meaning equivalent?

Example:

> Some romantic gestures only happen during a relationship's honeymoon
>   stage.
>
> Some romantic gestures only happen during a relationship's stage of
>   honeymoon.

(The reason I'm asking this is because I want to have Y at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the meaning of "X's Y" and "Y of X" is the same (for example, "the dog's collar" and "the collar of the dog") but there are many cases in which only one is idiomatically correct.  For your specific example, they're not the same.

**honeymoon stage** is normal and idiomatic.  It's how I would phrase it.  It's an example of a [*noun adjunct*](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html): a noun ("honeymoon") used to modify another noun ("stage").

But **relationship's stage of honeymoon** doesn't sound correct or fluent.  The phrasing *X of Y* means that X belongs to Y, so *stage of honeymoon* makes it sound like the stage belongs to the honeymoon, not the relationship.

Is there a particular reason that you want the word *honeymoon* at the end of the sentence?  It's hard to do because it works like an adjective, modifying something else.  If I had to put *honeymoon* at the end of the sentence, I might write something like

> the stage of the relationship called the honeymoon